# Jenkins pipeline, how to execute a sh from a script

Tags: git, jenkins, sh, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run a `sh` to fetch the git tags from a Jenkins script.
The sh is:

```
def tags = sh script: "git ls-remote --tags --refs ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx.git | cut -d'/' -f3", returnStdout: true
```

But it seems not to work. No idea why as Jenkins does not complain but `branchNames` is empty.
Following what I'm trying to run:

```
ProjectUtils.addProperties([
    [$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', 
        parameterDefinitions: [
            [$class: 'ExtensibleChoiceParameterDefinition',
                name: 'INSTALLER_BRANCH', description: 'The set of installers to be deployed.',
                editable: false,
                choiceListProvider: [$class: 'SystemGroovyChoiceListProvider',
                    scriptText: '''
                        def branchNames = ['master']
                        def tags = sh script: "git ls-remote --tags --refs ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx.git | cut -d'/' -f3", returnStdout: true
                        for (tag in tags) {
                            branchNames.push(tag)
                        }
                        return branchNames
                    ''',
                    usePredefinedVariables: true
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
])
```

I can call the `sh` before and it works:

```
stage ('installer') {
    println  "Checking Installer tags"
    def tags = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git ls-remote --tags --refs ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx.git | cut -d'/' -f3")
    println  "Installer tags:"
    println  tags
```

but then I don't know how to pass the variable `tags` to the script `'''<>'''`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: two suggestions, not sure if answers hence comments, inside the script can you try add a .trim() `def tags = sh(' script: "git ls-remote --tags --refs ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx.git | cut -d'/' -f3", returnStdout: true').trim()` If that doesnt work, change the script to Gstring """<>""" so you can use interpolation, pass in tags as ${tags}

Comment: Thanks but none of them work

Comment: Unfortunately I don‘t know much about declarative pipeline but what I know is that you cannot use pipeline steps like sh in the choice parameters script. That leaves you with option 2. you need to declare the tags variable globally in you Jenkinsfile. Than use it in the script using double quotes like “””$tags”””.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to get the tags as a string into a global variable. Inside the choices script you need then to parse that string and create an array `def tags = '$tags'.split(/\r?\n/)`. And to reference that variable in the script (which is a string itself inside the pipeline scirpt) you need to use double-quotes.

For a scripted pipeline something like this should work:

```
def tags = ""

node {
    stage ('installer') {
        println  "Checking Installer tags"
        tags = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git ls-remote --tags --refs ssh://git@bitbucket.gameforge.com:7999/gfclient/gfclient-installer.git | cut -d'/' -f3")
        println  "Installer tags:"
        println  tags
    }
}

ProjectUtils.addProperties([
    [$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', 
        parameterDefinitions: [
            [$class: 'ExtensibleChoiceParameterDefinition',
                name: 'INSTALLER_BRANCH', description: 'The set of installers to be deployed.',
                editable: false,
                choiceListProvider: [$class: 'SystemGroovyChoiceListProvider',
                    scriptText: """
                        def branchNames = ['master']
                        def tags = '$tags'.split('\n')
                        for (tag in tags) {
                            branchNames.push(tag)
                        }
                        return branchNames
                    """,
                    usePredefinedVariables: true
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
])
```

or if you want to add some groovy sugar to the script:

```
                    scriptText: """
                        def branchNames = ['master']
                        def tags = '$tags'.split('\n')
                        tags.each {tag ->
                            branchNames.push(tag)
                        }
                        branchNames
                    """,
```

or, going further:

```
                    scriptText: """
                        def branchNames = ['master']
                        def tags = '$tags'.split(/\r?\n/)
                        branchNames.addAll(tags)
                    """,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot test it as `def tags = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git ls-remote --tags --refs ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx.git | cut -d'/' -f3")` needs permissions and I have lost already too many hours. I solved adding a simple text field where we can write the tag by hand.